Doubt in a question involving summation of a harmonic progression
I was solving the question involving the sum of harmonic progression
Q) Given that  $$\color{red}{g(r) = 1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{4} + \dots + \frac{1}{r}}$$ and
$$\color{red}{\sum_{r=1}^{n}(2r+1)g(r) = P(n)g(n+1) - Q(n)}$$ where $P(n)$ and $Q(n)$ are polynomial functions of $n$.
Then evaluate (i) $\sum_{r=0}^{9} P(r)$ and (ii) $P(13) - G(13)$.
My Doubt: How can I approach the problem? Do we need to solve for the summation of the series?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

@Community Yes,  I will make the edit

Hint: First compute $P(n)$ and $Q(n)$, both of which turn out to be quadratic polynomials.

umm.. fine but how to evaluate Σ g(r)  as we don't know compact form for g(r)  so can you give any hint for that?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number#Identities_involving_harmonic_numbers

@RobPratt thanks... but I'm unable to dig out P(n) and Q(n)... getting stuck at Σr(g(r)? Can you please provide the solution?

We can show this relation by swapping the sums on the left-hand side and then using the summation formula $\sum_{k=1}^nk=\frac{1}{2}n(n+1)$. We obtain
\begin{align*}
{\color{blue}{\sum_{r=1}^n(2r+1)g(r)}}&=\sum_{r=1}^n(2r+1)\sum_{q=1}^r\frac{1}{q}\tag{1}\\
&=\sum_{q=1}^n\frac{1}{q}\sum_{r=q}^n(2r+1)\tag{2}\\
&=\sum_{q=1}^n\frac{1}{q}\left(2\left(\frac{1}{2}n(n+1)-\frac{1}{2}(q-1)q\right)+n-(q-1)\right)\\
&=\sum_{q=1}^n\frac{1}{q}\left(n^2+2n+1-q^2\right)\\
&=(n+1)^2\sum_{q=1}^n\frac{1}{q}-\frac{1}{2}n(n+1)\\
&\,\,\color{blue}{=(n+1)^2g(n+1)-\frac{1}{2}(n+1)(n+2)}
\end{align*}
and the claim follows.
Comment:

In (1) we swap the sums recalling
\begin{align*}
\sum_{r=1}^n\sum_{q=1}^r\Box=\sum_{1\leq q\leq r\leq n}\Box=\sum_{q=1}^n\sum_{r=q}^n\Box
\end{align*}

In (2) we use the above-mentioned summation formula, noting that
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=q}^n\Box = \sum_{k=1}^{n}\Box - \sum_{k=1}^{q-1}\Box
\end{align*}



thanks.. this seems easier and quick too

@Chetan: You're welcome. :-)

We use the following easily proved summation by parts formula:
$$\sum_{r=1}^n a_r (b_{r+1}-b_r) = a_{n+1} b_{n+1} - a_1 b_1 - \sum_{r=1}^n (a_{r+1}-a_r)b_{r+1}$$
Taking $a_r=g(r)$ and $b_r=r^2$ yields
\begin{align}
\sum_{r=1}^n (2r+1)g(r) 
&= \sum_{r=1}^n g(r) ((r+1)^2-r^2) \\
&= g(n+1) (n+1)^2 - g(1) 1^2 - \sum_{r=1}^n (g(r+1)-g(r))(r+1)^2 \\
&= g(n+1) (n+1)^2 - 1 - \sum_{r=1}^n \frac{1}{r+1}(r+1)^2 \\
&= g(n+1) (n+1)^2 - 1 - \sum_{r=1}^n (r+1) \\
&= g(n+1) (n+1)^2 - 1 - \frac{n(n+3)}{2} \\
&= g(n+1) (n+1)^2 - \frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{2}
\end{align}
So $P(n)=(n+1)^2$ and $Q(n)=(n+1)(n+2)/2$.

Great... Got it thanks
